# Conditional Expectation of a Product of Random Variables (Iterated Expectations)

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

I was looking through a friend's notes today and I saw an interesting exercise I wanted to try out. Unfortunately, I could not figure it out, so I turn to the internet.

"Given the model $$Y=\theta XU$$
where $U|X$ ~ $N(0,1)$ and $X$ & $\theta$ are strictly positive. What is the conditional expectation of Y given X?"

(It wasn't stated, but I assumed $\theta$ isn't a random variable but a constant. Not sure there).

My first instinct was that I need to do the Law of Iterated Expectations. The following is my rationale, so please let me know where I go wrong along the way.

Since we know $U|X$ ~ $N(0,1)$, we can say $E[U|X] = 0$. By Law of Iterated Expectations, this means $E[U] = 0$.

This next part is where I get tripped up. By law of Iterated Expectations, to get $E[Y|X]$, I'm not sure if the answer is $$E[E[Y|X]|X]$$ or $$E[E[Y|X]|U]$$

Either way, I get tripped up, and would appreciate insight in dealing with this problem. I haven't dealt too much with Iterated Expectations.

Comment: $$
\mathsf{E}[Y\mid X]=\mathsf{E}[\theta XU\mid X]=\theta X\mathsf{E}[U\mid X]\ldots
$$

Comment: OH MY GOD
I AM AN IDIOT

Comment: so  @d.k.o. his is supposed to go to 0 then, right? Cause $E[U|X] = 0$?